# Progress bar in listview with sql loader Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I use a loader for sqlite, handler thread (looper with queue) and a listview,

I need to show the user a progress bar while downloading the file inside the listview.

I'm thinking of the below but it doesn't look right as I'll be changing the data source a lot,

```
1 - User clicks "Download file icon" 
2 - Video starts downloading 
3 - Update the sql table with the progress 
4 - Notify the loader to reload the data 
5 - I have the code that keeps the list view at its current position after changing the data source
```

I can't think of another solution, is there any alternatives?

Comment: what about Cursor.getExtras()?

Comment: I haven't used this before, how can I use it?